# Как лучше хранить собраную статистику программы-демона?

Tags: c++, linux, json, хранение-данных, демон

Здравствуйте. Пишу программу-демон (на С++), сниффер пакетов, который отслеживает каждый IP и количество пакетов, что пришли от него. Иногда нужно будет выводить статистику о собранной информации. Вывод статистики должен быть устойчив от перезапуска демона или даже перезапуска компьютера. По этому я собираюсь хранить эту информацию в файле (например, в json формате). Так, как мне надо реализовать команду show [ip] count, то проще всего в моем случае хранить данные в map, где ключ - строка IP, значение к-во пакетов от данного IP. 
Вопрос: как(если не в json) удобнее всего хранить эту информацию?

Comment: А как вы это в оперативной памяти держать собираетесь. Вам же вероятно понадобится быстро находить нужную для обновления запись ... значит b-деревья, хеши ... А от этого уже плясать как хранить на диске, вам же надо это уметь грузить в индексированную структуру ... И с записью в файл надо быть аккуратным, а то вдруг будет перезапуск/перезагрузка именно в момент записи файла. А в json вам придется удалять предыдущий файл и писать целиком новый ...

Comment: И самое главное - ключ то какой, один адрес ipv4, т.е. 4 байта и сколько данных хранится на один ключ, сколько все счетчики для одного ключа занимают

Comment: @Mike, в обычном словаре буду хранить. Типа map из stl.  Ключем будет строка ip, значением - к-во пакетов данного ip. ничего особого из деревьями мудрить не собираюсь. Мне надо будет по команде `show [ip] count` выподиь к-во пакетов заданного ip.

Comment: JSON тогда, наверное, отпадает, если каждый раз надо переписывать его. Я хотел записывать в файл информацию каждый раз, когда ловим пакет. Тут удобно писать просто в конец файла.

Comment: Я бы предложил собирать информацию порциями, например по времени. И писать в постоянно растущий файл. Только конечно не из за каждого пакета, так диска не хватит. Когда файл достигает определенного объема - начинать следующий. И внешнюю программу, которая по этим файлам группирует информацию, что бы можно было удалять старые файлы. И даже при дозаписи следует быть осторожным, любая запись может оказаться записанной на половину. У меня подобная инфа пишется в XML подобном формате. При этом каждый блок данных пишется с контрольной суммой, что бы можно было найти повреждения файла

Comment: А еще вы не сказали, нужна ли в итоге статистика по времени например. Потому как если тупо счетчики с рождества христова, то можно сделать файл на юниксовой файловой системе (ext3/4, xfs), которая позволяет писать файл с дырками. Счетчик занимает например 4 байта, делаем 16ГБ двоичный файл, смещение в файле - ip в бинарном виде умноженный на 4. при записи используем прицельную запись, т.е. fseek на позицию ip*4, чтение-запись 4х байт. тогда физически на диске файл будет занимать меньше, только те блоки где есть данные

Comment: правда делать бекап такого файла не очень удобно, при копировании файл будет занимать полный объем. с другой стороны в сжатом виде совсем мало места.

Comment: имхо, sqlite сильно лучше и быстрее чем json

Comment: @vasily-vm, мне надо без установки сторонних программ. хочу, допустим, просто скомпилировать код программы на другом компе и что бы все работало. что если на этом компе нету sqlite? тогда просить установить? не самый подходящий вариант.

Comment: sqlite - библиотека

Comment: @vasily-vm, что если у меня данные про IP типа IPv4...(тоесть не строковый тип). Можно как то записать в таблицу mysql даные типа созданого пользователем?

Comment: не mysql а sqlite.  
можно все.   
можно создать таблицу, с полями соответствующими полям в пользовательском типе, можно blob....   
а ipv4 шикарно хранится в int32 ;)